# Ruby Hash weird behaviour

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a Ruby class which returns a Hash with lots of keys, some of which contain Fixint, other basic types, and some keys contain nested Hashes. Now I've faced a very weird behaviour with the Hash returned: if I do `puts myhash.keys` I get a list of keys in the Hash, if I do `myhash.each { |k, v| puts k, v }` I also get valid output of keys and values, **but** if I try to access a key directly, like `myhash["foo"]`, then it returns `nil`. The code in question is too big to post here, and I couldn't narrow the problem down to a smaller piece of code. Does anyone have suggestions on how can I further investigate this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found that the keys of the Hash were not pure strings, it was another type which behaved pretty much like a string when printed or assigned, which led to confusion. The keys were `BinData::Primitive` describing a length-prefixed string.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the correct key name? 'foo' and :foo is different keys:

```
> hash = { somekey: 'somevalue' }
=> {:somekey=>"somevalue"}
> hash[:somekey]
=> "somevalue"
> hash['somekey']
=> nil
```

bad idea:

```
hash['somekey'] = 'someothervalue'
> hash
=> {:somekey=>"somevalue", "somekey"=>"someothervalue"}
```

you can use 'active_suppot' gem to get indifferent access:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access'
> hash = { somekey: 'somevalue' }.with_indifferent_access
=> {"somekey"=>"somevalue"}
> hash[:somekey]
=> "somevalue"
> hash['somekey']
=> "somevalue"
```